# Unix grep command to return groups of rows in a textfile where it meets conditions

Tags: unix, awk, grep, find

I have a large text file containing the following records:

```
024567808 name date etc..
0376567 dfu ugig etc..
0388888 dtg hii etc..
032357 tuth gug etc..
025789 gkh kjkjk etc..
```

Using the grep command, I am able to retrieve the line containing a keyword.  How do I retrieve the next records if it starts with 03?

So for example I search for `name`, and it returns the first row.  I want this record along with all the 03 rows until the next 02 record.

output should be:

```
024567808 name date etc..
0376567 dfu ugig etc..
0388888 dtg hii etc..
032357 tuth gug etc..
```

I think grep is not powerful enough for this sort of task.  Perhaps awk could do it.  What is the best way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: I see that you've only tagged unix, grep and find, however awk could be useful for this. There's a good list of one liners here: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/awk1line.txt

Comment: Do you want a search for "Jo" to match if the line contains "John"? If your line is `024567808 Bob date Jo etc` do you want a search for "Jo" to match or should it only match if Jo appears in the 2nd field?

Comment: i am searching complete workd as 'name'

Comment: I don't know what "i am searching complete workd as 'name'" means so I don't know if/how that comment relates to both of my questions. Can you clarify maybe with just some yes/no answers or some additional sample input/output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
awk '/^02/{f=0} /name/{f=1} f' file
```

It all depends if you want "name" to only occur in a specific position on a line and whether or not you want "name" to only match if its not part of a longer word, e.g. do you want a search for "Jo" to match on "John"?

Comment: very clever answer!!  and your reputation `6669` looks nice, I want to break it! so +1